# What is the difference between checking X/Y/Z under Mirror in the side property panel's Tool's Options vs Creating a Mirror Modifier?

Tags: interface, mirror-modifier

it seems that there are two mirroring functions. One is from the Tool side property panel's Options and the other is under Modifier's Mirror. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure that it would make a big difference if you chose to work with the option rather than with the modifier. The X mirror option will symmetrize the editing, as long as your object is symmetrical (meaning you need to make sure that you won't disable the option at one moment). But generally the Mirror modifier is used when you model a symmetrical object because you're sure that your object stays symmetrical. I guess if you've applied the Mirror modifier and you need to make a small change, instead of using a Mirror modifier again you can simply temporarily enable the X mirror option.